# AWS lambda depending on event source, push the payload to different buckets/deliverystreams

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

My Lambda function ge[enter image description here][1]t's event form our backend solution. Right now it sends all the event.body to one delivery-stream which sends the data to a bucket. I would like to have different prefixes to my objects, so that i can create tables with a crawler for the same event-type data. When i crawl the data that comes in right now the schema of the table looks like this.

And when i open the payload struct it looks liek this inside
[enter image description here][2]

So in general i would like to only put the payload to the delivery-stream.
I was thinking of referring to the type columnname as this gives me information, where the data has been originally created.

Now to my question.

How can i refer to it in my lambda code and based on the value appearing in the type columnname put it to a specific delivery-stream

So I need to implement a if, elif structure and only put the payload to the delivery stream form the incoming data

```js
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

client = boto3.client('firehose')

def handler(event): 
    print(json.dumps(event, indent=4))
    try:
        response = client.put_record(
        DeliveryStreamName='string',
        Record={
            'Data': event.body
        }
    )
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps(f'Cannot process event: {e}')
        }

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({ 'ack': datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') })
    }
```

so instead of

```js
'Data': event.body
```

i need toput the payload only, but before puting the payload i need to specify to which bucket.
I don't know how to or where to add the if, elif structure and how to refer to the type column which is in the event body
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DKyw.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAjFM.png

Comment: There isn't a `?` anywhere in your question. That's a pretty good clue that you haven't stated your question clearly. I've ready your entire post and it is just a statement of intent, there is no question there. Where are you stuck? What problem are you encountering? What do you actually need help with?

Comment: I need help with the lambda code. How can I based on where the payload comes from,send it to different delivery streams.
You are right it seems a bit confusing, because in general i wanted to explain what i was thinking on how to deal with events coming from one backend solution which contain different payloads. And if this way which I described sound correct or if i should do a different lambda for each event type

Comment: It sounds like you just need to write an `if` statement. Are you having trouble with that? I'm also not sure why you included both Python and NodeJS code in your question. In general your question needs to be edited to focus on the exact issue you need help with.

Comment: yes exactly, i'm not sure where and how to put the if statement into the code , because i need to check for a specific value occuring in the event.body to know where to put the data to. that's why i wanted to ask in general if anyone has experience with incoming data from source and then depending on where the data originally has been created put it to the corresponding delivery stream

Comment: Please click the `edit` button under your question, and edit it appropriately to focus on your specific issue. I'm trying to help you conform your question to the site's requirements so your question isn't closed/deleted.